# Troubles viewing Git Gist on bl.ocks.org

Tags: git, d3.js, dimple.js, gist

I'm attempting to show off my new found power of dimple charting using git's gist and Mike Bostock's bl.ocky.org tool.  Each time I try to view one of my creations on bl.ocks by clicking on the [bl.ocks btn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VU52A.png) I arrive at a bl.ocks page that reads "file not found".  The inspector displays the following javascript error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Anyone know what I might be doing wrong?  I'm trying it with a singular and really simple html file in the gist to reduce error factors.

Here's a link to my gist:  https://gist.github.com/LIHTU/f498899bf2ad680f1429

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks, folks.

Answer (score 0):

I apparently forgot that I had to name my html file *index.html*.
Also, .js and .css files also have to be named *index.js* and *index.css*, I believe.

Comment: The required structure is documented on http://bl.ocks.org -- only `index.html` is required.